# Trust CA and parent CA, but not other derivative CAs. Java application

Tags: java, ssl

**EDIT 1**: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83972/trust-ca-and-parent-ca-but-not-other-derivative-cas . See comment. My client / server is in java, so the possible solution involves implementing my own  javax.net.ssl.TrustManager implementation.

I've got a problem with a client connecting to a server through an SSL-secured socket. I've got 3 CAs:

- root CA: used to sign other CA certs.
- testers CA: signed by root CA, used to sign beta-tester client certs.
- production CA: signed by root CA, used to sign production client certs.

I want to create a truststore for the server that:

- Allows all signed client certificates for the testers CA.
- Allows all signed client certificates for the root CA.
- Denies all signed client certificates for the production CA.

My problem: If i generate my truststore containing just the testers CA certificate then client certs signed by the root CA fails (I expected the certificate chain to allow it). If i generate my truststore containing both the testing CA and the root CA, certificates signed by production are also allowed.

Is there any way?

Comment: I don't think this is Java specific. You might get better answers over at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can you use 2 different root cas for signing test and production?

Comment: konstantin: I need to deploy a 'master' client managing both test and production, but i want to keep server truststores believing just its signing CAs, so what you purpose is affected by the problem too.

Comment: Thomas: Thanks, you're probably right... I'll see if there's any replies here and if not assume this is not java specific and ask this in security.stackschange.com.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83972/trust-ca-and-parent-ca-but-not-other-derivative-cas Seems that x509 certificate chain validation works like this and there's nothing to do involving just the trusted keystores. The only way to do this is implementing a custom certificate chain validation mechanism. As the possible solution is custom and my client/server is in java seems that the solution must be java-related finally. I'll try to post my own answer if i figure how to create a custom chain validator.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dirty way! You can break the chain for Server Cert -> Intermediate Cert ( Production CA) in you KeyStore so that the former can't be verified by Root CA.

Export the server certificate entry from Keystore and remove the issuer (Production CA) certificate from the PEM file and import it back.

```
>keytool -exportcert -rfc -file scert.pem -keystore store.jks -alias salias
```

Open the pem file , the first -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----<>-----END CERTIFICATE-----   is server certificate and below ones will be the issuer (Prod CA). Remove the issuer and import the .pem file back.

```
> keytool -importcert -keystore store.jks -alias salias -file broken.pem
```

Now when the Server cert is presented to the client it can't be verified by Root CA in TrustStore as the Server Cert -> Production CA-> Root CA is broken.

Comment: That would help in denying root signed certs while allowing derivative CAs. What i want is to allow root and one derivative CA but disallow the other.

Comment: This wouldn't deny Root signed I believe as we are breaking the chain between one particular derivative , production CA , and Root CA so that server certs issued by the former can't be verified by Root CA present in TrustStore. All certs signed by other derivatives and Root itself should pass.  You could give it a try.

Comment: Ah, ok, i get it. So the key is adding ALL sub CA certificates to truststore but ensuring i broke root CA chain in the certificates i do not want to trust... I'll give it a try and let you know.